# Prevent dynamodb scans by saving sorted and filtered record ids in the database

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm creating a serverless app and am looking for ways to get around doing costly scans with dynamodb.  I thought of a solution, but am not sure it will be reasonable in the long run.

First I would save records in a table normally:

```
{
  recordId1: {...recordData},
  recordId2: {...recordData},
  recordId3: {...recordData},
}
```

Then I'd set up a scheduled lambda function that gets all the records from a table, and saves a list of Ids for each combination of sorts and filters. This function would run after adding or deleting of records.

```
// I figure I'll make the ids for this table a hash of the object
// containing the sorts and filters, these ids are just for the example.
{
    sortFilterCombination1: [record3, record2, record1],
    sortFilterCombination2: [record3, record3, record1],
}
```

Then once a user goes to a list page, I would get the entire list of ids and bulk get the first page of records. Then more bulk gets for subsequent pages. This will prevent me from having to do scans every time a user hits a list page. For this site I imagine records wouldn't be added all that often, maybe 10-20x a day.

Some potential issues I've thought of:

- The lists of ids may get very large, but I figure once they hit a
  certain size, I can just chunk them into smaller lists
  `sortFilterCombination1Part1` `sortFilterCombination1Part2` etc
- Getting all records into a lambda function may be costly

So is this a good design pattern? I haven't really seen it anywhere, so I'm thinking there may be some holes in it.

Comment: so, you're inventing indexes the way they are implemented in relational databases

Comment: @Lashane can you elaborate on what you mean? Are you suggesting just using a relational DB? I'd like to keep this project serverless.

Comment: Just google about index implementation in RDBMS, how they update indexes, it will give you idea how you can do it